# How to implement data delete function in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, function, filter

In the edit page of our website, I have a list of mat cards/workspaces and there are edit icon at the top corner of each workspaces. by click that edit icon, it took you to the edit page for that workspace and I have a delete button in there that show a dialog box when it click and allow user to decide if they really want to delete that workspace or not.

Not really sure what to do for the API Call

```
 .name.length > 0 && this.description.length > 0) {
      //map
      this.workspace.name = this.name;
      this.workspace.description = this.description;
      this.workspace.type = WorkspaceType.public; //all workspaces that are created are public by default

      //create
      this.workspaceService.createWorkspace(this.workspace).subscribe(workspace => {
        this.saving = false;
        this.gotoManage();
        this.snackbar.open(this.workspace.name+ " has been created!!", "", {duration :2500});
      }, () => this.saving = false);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
openModalConfirmationDialog(content1: TemplateRef<any>, row, content2:TemplateRef<any>, content3: TemplateRef<any>) {
// you can store row or data selected until page is active
  this.contetntIWantToDelete = row;
// Make availale data in popup for confirmation
    this.modalService.open(content1).then(result => {
        if (result) {
        // load the data (row) which is to be deleted
            this.modalService.open(content2);
        // update delete
     this.yourDeleteinfoAPIcustomFunction('/name1/requestedWorkspaceDelete', row.id, content3);
        }
    });
}

yourDeleteinfoAPIcustomFunction(url, param, content1: TemplateRef<any>) { 
// This function have success and error messages based on what is selected for deletion
 this.http.get(baseUrl + url, options)
        .subscribe(r => {
                if (r != null) {
                   // success delete operation
                } else {
                    // failed delete op.
                }
            }
```

}

in your html on delete button:

```
(click)="openModalConfirmationDialog(modalConfirm, row, modalDeleteProgress, modalDeleteSuccess)"
```

In above function: I have this set of dialogs which are passed in function, as you mentioned you want to get confirmation from dialog:

```
<ng-template #modalConfirm>
    <custom-directive>
        <p>Confirm delete operation</p>
        <p>Delete workspace Id: <B>{{workspace.id}}
            <br></B><B>{{moreDetails}}</B>
    </custom-directive>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #modalDeleteProgress>
    <custom-directive type="warning" warningTitle="Delete in progress">
    </custom-directive>
</ng-template>

 <ng-template #modalDeleteSuccess>
    <custom-directive type="success" successTitle="Success" btn="Close">
        <div>workspace ID: {{workspace.id}} has been deleted</div>
    </custom-directive>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I understand that it's hard for you to understand the business behind my projects but I'm kinda confused with your code. My friend told me to do some logic in the code above and when I compare to your code, It seem like I having a hard time understanding it. I added the code for how we create a new workspace.

Comment: Ohh yes, actually i do not have simplest example for this one, but let me explain further what exactly happening, i will update my answer

Comment: Ok.. Since we are using API call from database and I've never done that before so I'm not sure how to do it. I copy some of the code from how we create a new workspace in my dialog component but not sure what to do from there to delete workspace. Also do you think I need a new api call or I can use the same code from create new workspace ( The first code box )

Comment: I updated ans with more details, For sure you will need a new API for deletion or else how your records will be updated for workspaces if you are having something like 'getAllWorkspaces()', in anser '/name1/requestedWorkspaceDelete' is delete operation API, here is one simple example, but you should have your own delete operation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-delete-confirm

Comment: Thanks you suhas for your help

Comment: @aasenomad Please upvote or mark answer accordingly, if solution helped you in any possible ways.